# MS Access: How do you design a database for students choosing subjects

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-design, relational-database

I am currently trying to design a database where we have a table of students, table of subjects available and the table containing which students will choose which subjects based on a form they fill in. Similiar to an order system.

I think my design is rather simple and not reliable.

I currently have three tables:

```
TableModule: 
  ModuleID(PK), 
  ModuleName, 
  Semester, 
  Credits 

TableModuleForm: 
  ID(PK), 
  StudentID, 
  ModuleID 

TableStudent: 
  StudentID(PK), 
  Username, 
  Password, 
  Lastname, 
  Firstname, 
  Email,
  Course,
  StudyYear
```

Not quite sure if using 3 tables is the correct method. I am just a beginner in MS

- What is a good method to design a database where students can choose multiple subjects they want to study all in one form?
  *What sort of relationships should they have?

I currently have implemented a login form where it will allow access to the subject selection form after they have logged in using the correct username and password based on information in the students table. Thanks!

Comment: Post your existing table schemas.

Answer (score 1):

```
Student
  id
  name
  username
  password

Subject
  id
  name

StudentSubject
  id
  subject_id
  student_id
```

Comment: I currently have three tables:
TableModule: ModuleID(PK), ModuleName, Semester, Credits
TableModuleForm: ID(PK), StudentID, ModuleID
TableStudent: StudentID(PK), Username, Password, Lastname, Firstname, Email,Course,StudyYear.

       Not quite sure if using 3 tables is the correct method. I am just a beginner in MS Access

Comment: @KangCheSun It is **really relevant** that you are using an array of fields. The number of tables is not quite so relevant. If you do not show your existing schemas, you will not get a realistic reply.

Comment: Note also that you undoubtedly need to complete a certain number of modules for a complete course, so how do you intend to group the modules? Consider a sales database, you have customers (students), orders (courses) and order details (modules).

Comment: I was hoping to set the modules with a set number of credits. Then providing a validation button to use If statement to check whether they have chosen too many or too little credits required.